# Payara micro on VsCode gets java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, glassfish, indexoutofboundsexception, payara-micro

I'm trying to debug a glassfish project on VsCode, I chose to run a micro payara from the extension and the executor service task gets an index out of bounds exception.

```
[2021-12-02T08:11:06.092-0400] [] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00006] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=88 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1638447066092] [levelValue: 800] JMXStartupService has disabled JMXConnector system

[2021-12-02T08:11:32.329-0400] [] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=payara-executor-service-task] [timeMillis: 1638447092329] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting jersey/repackaged/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMapBasedMultimap$RandomAccessWrappedList.class of size 2105
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.MethodModelImpl.getParameter(MethodModelImpl.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.ModelClassVisitor$ModelMethodVisitor.visitParameterAnnotation(ModelClassVisitor.java:392)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readParameterAnnotations(ClassReader.java:2932)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1467)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:717)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:44)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2021-12-02T08:11:32.460-0400] [] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=payara-executor-service-task] [timeMillis: 1638447092460] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting jersey/repackaged/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMapBasedMultimap$WrappedCollection.class of size 6672
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.MethodModelImpl.getParameter(MethodModelImpl.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.ModelClassVisitor$ModelMethodVisitor.visitParameterAnnotation(ModelClassVisitor.java:392)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readParameterAnnotations(ClassReader.java:2932)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1467)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:717)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:44)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2021-12-02T08:11:32.495-0400] [] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=payara-executor-service-task] [timeMillis: 1638447092495] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting jersey/repackaged/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMapBasedMultimap$WrappedList.class of size 5708
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.MethodModelImpl.getParameter(MethodModelImpl.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.ModelClassVisitor$ModelMethodVisitor.visitParameterAnnotation(ModelClassVisitor.java:392)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readParameterAnnotations(ClassReader.java:2932)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1467)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:717)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:44)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2021-12-02T08:11:32.503-0400] [] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=payara-executor-service-task] [timeMillis: 1638447092503] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting jersey/repackaged/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMapBasedMultimap$WrappedSortedSet.class of size 4003
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.MethodModelImpl.getParameter(MethodModelImpl.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.impl.ModelClassVisitor$ModelMethodVisitor.visitParameterAnnotation(ModelClassVisitor.java:392)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readParameterAnnotations(ClassReader.java:2932)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1467)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:717)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:44)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

I'm not sure if this has to do with the XML bind hack needed to run a Java8 project on VsCode since Payara Extension uses the env JAVA_HOME and JDK (which for the project should be Java8 but Java11 is needed as JAVA_HOME/JDK_HOME for Java extensions to work).

Edit: the instance seems to keep running just fine despite the exception.

```
[2021-12-02T08:12:23.124-0400] [] [INFO] [] [PayaraMicro] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1638447143124] [levelValue: 800] 
Payara Micro URLs:



[2021-12-02T08:12:23.127-0400] [] [INFO] [] [PayaraMicro] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1638447143127] [levelValue: 800] Payara Micro  5.2021.5 #badassmicrofish (build 770) ready in 111,507 (ms)
```

Edit: When executing:

```
mvn fish.payara.maven.plugins:payara-micro-maven-plugin:start -X
```

The exception does not occur. So it seems it is a problem with the plugin.

Comment: Hi Rubén, I have the same issue with my Payara Micro. Did you find out what's caused the exceptions?

Comment: I ended up not using the plugin, and never managed to fix the error.